# Filter Selected options when values included inside an array

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have this javascript code :

```js
var NotWanted = ['apple','banana','lemon'];
```

and this HTML code:

```html
<select id="Fruits">     
  <option value="apple"  > Red apple     </option>     
  <option value="banana" > Yellow banana </option>     
  <option value="orange" > Orange orange </option>     
  <option value="lemon"  > Yellow lemon  </option> 
</select>
```

how can I hide the 3 not wanted elements based on their value ?

Real data have more than 100 options so I should find a way to filter it for many elements.

Whatever I found while searching is based on the description of the select menu and not on the values.. My guess is I should try and add a class or an ID in each select value ?

Answer (score 1):

this way:

(both previous answers let `Red apple` as default select)

-- `hidden` property is also good, but not always supported on some  older browser versions.

But anyway, to respect the HTML logic, an unusable option must be marked as disabled.

```js
function filterSelectOption( select_ID, notWanted_Arr )
  {
  const eSelect = document.getElementById(select_ID);
  eSelect.value = '';  // === select default is none
  
  [...eSelect.options]  // same as Array.from(eSelect.options)
  .forEach( opt =>
    {
    opt.disabled = notWanted_Arr.includes( opt.value );
    // or (without needs of css) :
    // opt.disabled = opt.hidden = notWanted_Arr.includes( opt.value ); 
    
    if (!opt.disabled && eSelect.value === '')
      opt.selected = true;
      // eSelect.value = opt.value; // set the default select
    })
  }
```

```css
/* use CSS to temporary "remove" unwanted elements */

select option[disabled] {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<button
  onclick="filterSelectOption('Fruits',['apple','banana','lemon'])">
  no apple or banana or lemon
</button>

<button
  onclick="filterSelectOption('Fruits', ['orange','lemon'] )">
  no orange or lemon 
</button>

<button
  onclick="filterSelectOption('Fruits', [])">
  show all 
</button>
<br><br>

<select id="Fruits">     
  <option value="apple"  > Red apple     </option>     
  <option value="banana" > Yellow banana </option>     
  <option value="orange" > Orange orange </option>     
  <option value="lemon"  > Yellow lemon  </option> 
</select>
```